# Ajax Proxy in WebSphere Portal

Tags: websphere-portal

I am not able to make the ajax proxy work in WebSphere Portal 8. I tried using the Application specific ajax proxy method.

Below are my proxy config xml and web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy:proxy-rules
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:proxy="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sw/ajax/proxy-config/1.1">
<proxy:mapping url="http://api.wunderground.com/api/<key>/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json" contextpath="/get/weatherData" />
<proxy:policy url="http://api.wunderground.com/api/<key>/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json" acf="none">
    <proxy:actions>
        <proxy:method>GET</proxy:method>
    </proxy:actions>
    <proxy:headers></proxy:headers>
    <proxy:mime-types></proxy:mime-types>
    <proxy:cookies></proxy:cookies>
    <proxy:users></proxy:users>             
</proxy:policy>
<proxy:ipfilter></proxy:ipfilter>
</proxy:proxy-rules>
```

web.xml

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ProxyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.ibm.wps.proxy.servlet.ProxyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ProxyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/get/weatherData</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: What specific error or problem you are experiencing with your config?

Comment: I see this exception in logs,

    com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[ProxyServlet]: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1127)
    at com.ibm.mm.proxy.servlet.AjaxProxyServlet.service(AjaxProxyServlet.java:242)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)

Answer (score 0):

The issue need to be inside of the ajax proxy xml you copied. the  is corrupting the xml syntax of the document.

An XML validator (like https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ ) shows this error

The value of attribute "url" associated with an element type "proxy:mapping" must not contain the '<' character.

You could use the following mapping config to correct the problem then all information appended to get/weatherData will be attached to /api/.

```
<proxy:mapping
        url="http://api.wunderground.com/api/"
        contextpath="/get/weatherData" />
```

As I do not know what  means in your application maybe it would be as simple as replacing  with the real value

Comment: As I didn't want to share my key I have put <key> in the url when I posted here, in actual I don't have any angular braces in the url.

This is the URL

http://api.wunderground.com/api/21ad4557286e407b/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json

Comment: And this is the target URL for my Ajax call

`code` '<%= renderResponse.encodeURL(renderRequest.getContextPath() + "/get/weatherData") %>' `code`